# Retrieving p values in R, using clm()

Tags: r, regression, ordinal-data, ordered-logit

I have run ordinal regression in RStudio using two different packages, relaxing the proportional odds assumption for predictor `PROXIMITY`. My ordinal response has 3 levels.

Using VGAM and vglm(), the output is roughly something like this:

`> Coefficients: 
                          Estimate    Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|) 
(Intercept):1              0.5117320  0.5437684   0.941      0.346662 
(Intercept):2             -0.7123845  0.4982063  -1.430      0.152746
PROXIMITY2:1               1.1099603  0.4781458   2.321      0.020266 * 
PROXIMITY2:2               0.8870411  0.4860655   1.825      0.068010 
PROXIMITY3:1               0.7963931  0.2106141   3.781      0.000156 ***
PROXIMITY3:2               1.2027518  0.2720969   4.420      9.86e-06 ***
HAB                       -0.0096147  0.0024824  -3.873      0.000107 ***`

And then using clm() in the ordinal package, the output is:

`> Coefficients:
                            Estimate   Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|) 
HAB                         -0.009615   0.002511   -3.828    0.000129 ***`

`> Threshold coefficients:
                            Estimate   Std. Error z value
1|2.PROXIMITY2              -1.10996    0.48137  -2.306
2|3.PROXIMITY2              -0.88704    0.48672  -1.822
1|2.PROXIMITY3              -0.79640    0.21145  -3.766
2|3.PROXIMITY3              -1.20274    0.27188  -4.424`

You can see that when using clm(), the predictor for which the assumption is relaxed, `PROXIMITY`, is shown under threshold coefficients, and no p values are produced. My question is, is there a reason for this?

How can I retrieve the p values when using the clm() approach?

Thanks!

Comment: The `clm` is semi-parametric: it treats the thresholds as nuisance parameters. If they aren't a nuisance, you should use a different model. Consider just a plain old log-linear model.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me that this is mostly about statistics, so I am voting to leave it open.

Comment: Hi @AdamO, I have chosen to use partial proportional odds models since the predictor `PROXIMITY`, for example, violates the proportional odds assumption. So, it *is* seemingly a nuisance. My real models have several more variables, approximately 3 of which violate the assumption. I have used the above as a small example.

I am just wondering why the p-values aren't provided in the standard output for `clm`. Perhaps it is because they would be technically invalid - I'm not sure, this is what I'm struggling with (my understanding of stats is fairly basic).

Comment: For anyone who reads this question - I have figured out that I can retrieve the p-values by using the `coef(model.summary)` function, which appears to be part of the `stats4` package. I found this information from an old thread here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Ordinal-logistic-regression-p-values-td3777674.html

It looks to me me like the z and p values are calculated differently between `clm()` and `vglm()`.